# When does a mod_fcgid process get stopped?

Tags: php, mod-fcgid

As far as I know for every request a mod_fcgid process is started. I would like to understand when/why a mod_fcgid process is stopped? Does a PHP Fatal error stop/remove a process?

Background of my question is that i would like to know if a PHP fatal error could be a cause for several zombie mod_fcgid processes. Unfortunately I have no access to the server to provide you with more information on the server. The only things I can see are the access / error logs.

First I would like to understand how mod_fcgid processes are started and stopped, like described in the beginning.

Thank you very much for your help

Kind regards!